# Bolt npm : Could not find a workspace named "client"

Tags: node.js, express, package.json, monorepo

I'm trying to manage my existing monorepo project with [Bolt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bolt).I did all basic setup required by this library. But still getting the below error. tried to find the solution on google also but could not get any help.

But when I run `Bolt start` command it gives me the below error;

```
[0] (bookmarkify.in) $ yarn run -s start:client error Could not find a workspace named "client" from "/Users/spratap/Personal/bookmarkify.in"
[1] (bookmarkify.in) $ yarn run -s start:server error Could not find a workspace named "server" from "/Users/spratap/Personal/bookmarkify.in"
[0] error Error: error Could not find a workspace named "client" from "/Users/spratap/Personal/bookmarkify.in"
[0] error     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/spratap/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/bolt/dist/modern/utils/processes.js:128:16)
[0] bolt start:client exited with code 1
[1] error Error: error Could not find a workspace named "server" from "/Users/spratap/Personal/bookmarkify.in"
[1] error     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/spratap/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/bolt/dist/modern/utils/processes.js:128:16)
[1] bolt start:server exited with code 1
error Error
error     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/spratap/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/bolt/dist/modern/utils/processes.js:128:16)
```

Not sure why this error is coming.

```
 Root
 |-node_modules
 |-packages
 | |--client
 | |--server
 |-package.json
```

**Root Package.json**

```
  {
"name": "my-monorepo",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"private": true,
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently \"bolt start:client\" \"bolt start:server\" ",
  "start:client": "bolt w client run start",
  "start:server": "bolt w server run start",
  "build": "bolt w client run build",
  "build:client": "bolt w client run build"
},
"bolt": {
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/client/*",
    "packages/server/*"
  ]
},
"dependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^8.2.0"
}
```

}

**Client Package.json**

```
  {
"name": "client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.7.1",
  "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
  "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
  "@react-oauth/google": "^0.11.0",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
  "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
  "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
  "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
  "framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
  "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
  "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "typescript": "^4.9.5",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
}
```

}
**Server Package.json**

```
  {
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"type": "module",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "nodemon src/index.js"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
  "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
  "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "google-auth-library": "^8.9.0",
  "mongoose": "^7.3.4",
  "morgan": "^1.10.0"
}
```

}